# ¿Puedo usar Sublime Text para uso comercial?

Tags: sublimetext

Tengo una inquietud:

¿Puedo usar Sublime Text para uso comercial, o debo pagar por el uso de éste?

Comment: Antes de que voten por cerrar esta pregunta recuerden que las preguntas sobre herramientas de desarrollo si tienen lugar en este sitio.

Answer (score 2):

El producto se puede descargar para propósitos de evaluación (prueba); pero si se va a utilizar de manera contínua, se debe adquirir una licencia.

> Sublime Text may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a license must be purchased for continued use.
>      Licenses are per-user, rather than per-machine, so you can enjoy Sublime Text on as many computers and operating systems as you wish with your license.

Hay información más detallada en la página de [preguntas frecuentes](http://www.sublimetext.com/sales_faq).

Answer (score 1):

Se distribuye de forma gratuita, sin embargo no es software libre o de código abierto, se puede obtener una licencia para su uso ilimitado, pero el no disponer de ésta no genera ninguna limitación más allá de una alerta cada cierto tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

La licencia que ellos brindan es para poder dar soporte y obtener acceso a algunas funcionalidades del programa.

**Su licencia es personal, no por maquina**

En su [sitio](http://www.sublimetext.com/buy) ofrecen la licencia para empresas que simplemente brinda la opcion de adquirir varias licencias para varias personas.

Como bien se dice, no es de codigo abierto, pero no limita ni obliga a los usuarios a adquirilas para poder desarrollar y comerciar proyectos.